# Verilog sum problem

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, simulation

I have an array named `mixed_signal`, and I need to sum of its elements in a register but it cannot be sequential. Can you help me?

```
wire signed [N-1:0] mixed_signal   [8:0];
assign mixed_signal[0]=coeffs[0]*noisy_in;
generate
genvar j;

    for(j=1;j<tap;j=j+1)begin

        assign mixed_signal[j]= coeffs[j]*delayed_signal[j-1];

    end
endgenerate
```

All off the code is given below

```
module filter_fir(clk,rst, noisy_in,filtered_out

);
parameter N=16; // Size of the data
parameter tap=9;

input                   rst,clk;
input          [N-1:0] noisy_in;
output reg [N-1:0] filtered_out;

reg [N-1:0] coeffs [tap-1:0];
wire signed [N-1:0] delayed_signal   [8:0];
wire signed [N-1:0] mixed_signal   [8:0];
wire signed [N-1:0] sum                 ;


initial begin
coeffs[0]=16'h04F6;
coeffs[1]=16'h0AE4;
coeffs[2]=16'h1089;
coeffs[3]=16'h1496;
coeffs[4]=16'h160F;
coeffs[5]=16'h1496;
coeffs[6]=16'h1089;
coeffs[7]=16'h0AE4;
coeffs[8]=16'h04F6;
end

ddf delay_call(.rst(rst),.clk(clk),.data_delayed(delayed_signal[0]),.data_in(noisy_in));

generate 
genvar i;

    for(i=0;i<(tap-1);i=i+1)begin 
    
        ddf delay_call(.rst(rst),.clk(clk),.data_delayed(delayed_signal[i+1]),.data_in(delayed_signal[i]));
  
    end

endgenerate

assign mixed_signal[0]=coeffs[0]*noisy_in;
generate
genvar j;

    for(j=1;j<tap;j=j+1)begin

        assign mixed_signal[j]= coeffs[j]*delayed_signal[j-1];

    end
endgenerate

//Here I need A combinational sum = sum + mixed_signal[j] 
//functionality, similar to C,

always@(posedge clk)begin
    
    filtered_out<=sum;

end 
endmodule

module ddf (rst,clk,data_in,data_delayed);

parameter  N=16;
parameter tap=9;

input                   clk,rst;
input      [N-1:0]      data_in;
output reg [N-1:0] data_delayed;

always@(posedge clk)begin

    if(rst) data_delayed<=0;
    else    data_delayed<=data_in;

end   

endmodule
```

Comment: @toolic The problem is that I need sum = sum + mixed_signal[j] functionality, similar to C, but in RTL, I understand that I can't directly connect the input to the output. Is there a solution for this? (mixed_signal is multidimensional array)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to generate the sum in combinitorial, you can modify mixed_signal to be the partial sum of all lesser signals:

```
wire signed [N-1:0] mixed_signal   [8:0];
wire signed [N-1:0] sum;
assign mixed_signal[0]=coeffs[0]*noisy_in;
generate
genvar j;

    for(j=1;j<tap;j=j+1)begin

        assign mixed_signal[j]= mixed_signal[j-1] + coeffs[j]*delayed_signal[j-1];

    end
endgenerate
assign sum = mixed_signal[tap - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty standard way to sum up the values of an array in Verilog:

```
reg signed [N-1:0] sum;

// ...

integer s;
always @* begin
    sum = 0;
    for (s=0; s<tap; s=s+1) begin
        sum = sum + mixed_signal[s];
    end
end
```

Note that `sum` is now a `reg` instead of a `wire`.

You may need to increase the bit width of `sum`.  Generally, the sum of 9 16-bit values requires more than 16 bits.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already tried it but it connects input of the adder to the output of adder. That's why it cannot be implemented.

Comment: @EmreYILDIZ: What software did you try it with?  Simulation, synthesis, other?  Edit your question with new information instead of here in the comments.